# node.js sendgrid with multiple recipients get blank value when adding substitution

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, sendgrid

i found issue when sending email to multiple recipients using sendgrid.
i got blank value when adding substitution.

technologies

- node.js
- sendgrid (v2)

==== my sample code (node.js) ====

```
const SENDGRID_API_KEY = 'KEY'
const sendgrid = require('sendgrid')(SENDGRID_API_KEY)

function sendEmailToSupport() {
  const email = new sendgrid.Email({
      from: 'jaewwalletsupport@paysbuy.co.th',
      to: ['user_a@gmail.com', 'user_b@gmail.com', 'user_c@gmail.com']
      html: '<div>test = :test</div>',
      subject: 'dummy'
    })

  email.addSubstitution(':test', 'ddddddddddddd')
  sendgrid.send(email, (err, response) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      console.log('Yay! Our templated email has been sent')
    }
  })
}

module.exports = {
  sendEmailToSupport
}
```

====== result ======

- user_a@gmail.com gets email with correct content `test = ddddddddddddd`
- user_b@gmail.com, user_c@gmail.com get email with blank value `test =`

it looks like the first email in the `email.to` array will get the correct content, others get blank data.

in the sendgrid web admin, there is no error, everying is fiine.

how to fix this issue?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after analyse the sendgrid lib, i found the solution now by editing this line

```
email.addSubstitution(':test', new Array(email.to.length).fill('ddddddddddddd'))
```